# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object on line 19

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

class Product {

    const SHOW_BY_DEFAULT = 10;

    public static function getLatestProducts($count = self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT) {

        $count = intval($count);

        $db = Db::getConnection();

        $productList = array();

        $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name, new FROM product WHERE status = "1" LIMIT'.$count);

        $i = 0;

        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $productList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $productList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $productList[$i]['new'] = $row['new'];
            $i++;
        }

        return $productList;
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\OpenServer\domains\keram\models\product.php on line 19

Comment: Ок, у вас ошибка на строке 19. Какая это строка в вышеприведённом коде? (вероятно, `while ($row = $result->fetch())`) В чём вопрос?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так вроде очевидно, что 19-я это `while ($row = $result->fetch()) {` :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: вроде да, но не факт)) И при наличии кода и очевидного сообщения об ошибке остаётся непонятным: а в чём вопрос? Нужно перевести сообщение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, интерпретатор Вам же пишет: в такой-то линии, Вы пытаетесь вызвать функции `fetch()` у переменной, что не является объектом.
`$result` - проверяйте тип, ошибки DB после вызова `$db->query`.

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался)